# Ajax issue with "oninput" event

Tags: php, ajax, events

i'm trying to fire an **oninput** event on a number input field, the ajax call is always successful and showing the parameter sent in firebug's network-> params, however, when i want to retrieve the parameter sent via ajax, the isset() is not working and never getting a reply, for more clarification i will post parts of my code below :

```
<label> Amount to Pay </label>
<div id="toBePaid" class="form-input-wide">
          <input type="number" id="amountToBePaid" name="amountToBePaid" oninput="getRemainingAmount()" data-type="input-number" min="0" required style="width:100px;" size="5" value="<?php  ?>"  data-component="number" /> 
 </div>
```

this previous  the number that will be sent via ajax, the function is : `getRemainingAmount()`

```
<label> Remaining Amount </label>
<div id="remaining" >
 </div>
```

this div will contain the reply, it will be referenced in the script

```
function getRemainingAmount() { 
var amountToPay = $('#amountToBePaid').val();
var dataString = "amountToPay="+amountToPay;
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
         url:'http://192.168.0.10/skylite/test',
        data: dataString,
        success: function(response) {
          $("#remaining").empty();
                    $(response).find('.resultRemaining').each(function(){
                $('#remaining').append($(this).html()); });                   
        },      
    });
}
```

Now i will post "test" page, please note that the `.empty()` is not the issue, the test page's code contain :

```
if(isset($_POST['amountToPay'])) {

 var $AmountToPay=$_POST['amountToPay'];

  echo "<div class='resultRemaining'>";
 echo "<input type='number' id='remainingAmount' name='remainingAmount' data-type='input-number' disabled style='width:100px;'   size='5' value=".$AmountToPay."  data-component='number' />"; 

       echo "</div>";
    } else {
      // redirecting to my main page here
    }
```

i'm appending `resultRemaining` class to the function, if i remove my  `if(isset($_POST['amountToPay'])) {` the reply works if i input a dummy value.

Here's a small snapshot of the ajax call in "Network":

[image]

Comment: What do you get if you do: `console.log(response);` in the success callback?

Comment: I tried the first suggestion but it's still the same, still getting successful ajax calls with the correct parameter but no html reply because of the if isset

Comment: I would also suggest adding `dataType: 'json'`, to your Ajax and return JSON from PHP instead of HTML, since you only want the values anyway.

Comment: That PHP code should throw a parse error. Change `var $AmountToPay=$_POST['amountToPay'];` to `$AmountToPay=$_POST['amountToPay'];` (remove the `var`). Demo: https://3v4l.org/InhN7

Comment: @MagnusEriksson hey magnus, the log returns html of body / navbar and everything i'm pulling dynamically to a page such as scripts, that's why i'm using .find(class name) so it only replies this specific div, which is working perfectly with other scenarios

Comment: So when you're doing an ajax call, your always returning a complete HTML page and only select the value? That seems _very_ inefficient.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson thank you, i didn't realize there was a var until now, but i'm sure it wasn't there before! Thank you again it worked perfectly !

Comment: @MagnusEriksson Post it as an answer to flag as accept  / vote up, thanks again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your PHP code is invalid and will throw a parse error, since you have `var` in front of your variable. The keyword `var` was used in PHP 4 to declare class members. It *can* still be used (but seldom is) for declaring public class members, but it's not a valid keyword in any other context.

It should work if you change the line:

```
var $AmountToPay=$_POST['amountToPay'];
```

to

```
$AmountToPay=$_POST['amountToPay'];
```

Demo about `var`: http://3v4l.org/InhN7